# How to add KeyListener to JComponent when mouse is entered?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jcomponent

I have created custom button class which extends `JComponent` and want to add `KeyListener` on `mouseEntered` event (and later remove on `mouseExited`). So my goal is - when the mouse enters this `JComponent` - then if I press Enter - some code will be executed, related to only this button. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis : Don't use KeyListeners, use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). KeyListeners are way to low level from Swing's perspective :-)

Comment: Why don't you just use a boolean that will control the execution of particular key events based on the mouse position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto) instead of KeyListeners, since the latter is way to low level for `Swing`. Just bring your mouse over the `JButton`, and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then take your mouse outside the bounds of the `JButton` and try pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again. Have a look at this example and see if this is what you wanted :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonBinding {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField tField;
    private JButton button;
    private KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");

    private Action action = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.println("Action Performed");
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
    };

    private MouseAdapter mouseActions = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
            System.out.println("Mouse Entered");
            JButton button = (JButton) me.getSource(); 
            button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, "enter");
            button.getActionMap().put("enter", action);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
            System.out.println("Mouse Exited");
            JButton button = (JButton) me.getSource();
            button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, "none");
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
    };  

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Binding Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        tField = new JTextField(10);
        button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.addMouseListener(mouseActions);

        contentPane.add(tField);
        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ButtonBinding().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the nice example using keyBindings. Nitpicking: a) actions have an enabled property, so no need to add/remove the binding b) the mouseEvent carries its source, so no need to access an external field c) a JPanel is opaque by default

Comment: @kleopatra : Thankyou and KEEP SMILING :-) Though I read in Java Tutorials, that `JPanel` is opaque by default, though not for all `LookAndFeels` that's why I always use to call this property on `JPanel` by setting background on it :-) as seen in this [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html). Though OP said, that he/she wants to remove it at `Mouse Exit`, hence I did that thingy :(

Comment: good point about opaqueness, tend to forget that the LAF might decide otherwise :-) As to OP's requirement: typically it's not fully specified, here I think the important part is that triggering the action should be _possible only_ when the mouse is over the component - but that's guessing.

Comment: The solution works perfectly :) Just changed `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, null);` Thanks indeed!